# How to build and use ffmpeg within android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am prototyping a fairly simple camera app to test out using MediaRecorder to create a custom camera activity with one snag, I want to set the aspect ratio of recorded videos to a 1x1. Through much research I have found that this is only possible by using a library like FFMPEG to crop each frame of the video to the size I desire.

I have read many tutorials and articles on different ways to build FFMPEG into Android, but most of them are either outdated and use older versions of both the Android NDK and FFMPEG, or more recent ones just do not work when followed. I tried following the popular http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/‎ and a few other similar ones that all lead to an error about a missing pkg-config file because FFMPEG is generally meant to be installed on linux or another OS apparently. I found some information about building FFMPEG in android by using a make-standalone-toolchain.sh file here http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/blogs/2013/12/06/building-ffmpeg-for-android-on-x86 and can't make heads or tails as to how to go about using this method.

This now leads into my question: What is the best/proven way currently to build and use FFMPEG within android applications? If the standalone toolchain method is the way to go, is there any material better than the one listed that is easier to follow? I would even be open to a reliable template application with the FFMPEG Libraries ready to go (if this is possible); although, I would much rather know how to build this into android for future use.

Thank you in advance for any advice or suggestions on this issue.

Comment: You can use this,its easy to impement.
https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully build ffmpeg libraries using

https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/

You have to be on Ubuntu to build that.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I should have time to take a look at this soon which I will probably attempt to build a template project out of this. If I am not successful in manually building ffmpeg into the ndk and this project solves my problem, I will be sure to mark this as the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Alex, I tried building the dolphinPlayer project both on the mac and Ubuntu operating systems and received the same error:  E/AndroidRuntime(13450):

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 22:07:42.563: E/AndroidRuntime(13450): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ffmpeg: findLibrary returned null`

I just imported the project name 'p' within the zip from the link above into ADT and attempted to run it as an application. Am I missing something? Once I can get this app to run on its own, then I should be able to make an empty android project out of it with ffmpeg libraries included yes?

Comment: Did you build the native part (which results in libffmpeg.so or something like that)? I believe it's in the 'p' directory and you build it with the NDK

Comment: Sorry it has been a while. I ran the compile.sh which built the ffmpeg library. So now that i got past that error, there are other native libraries that the application states is missing next in line being the sdl libraries. `System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg"); System.loadLibrary("sdl"); System.loadLibrary("sdl_ttf"); System.loadLibrary("sdl_image"); System.loadLibrary("iconv"); System.loadLibrary("universalchardet"); System.loadLibrary("yuv2rgb"); System.loadLibrary("application");`. These are all the libraries it is trying to load. Is there a script that needs to be run for these as well?

Comment: I just took ffmpeg.so from the build to my project and started using it. The dolphin player, I believe, yes, requires other libraries, too. I don't rememeber any problems building dolphin player, though, it builds smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the guide I liked the most: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/

If you need more options, you can take a look at these, which are equally good:

- https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg
- https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264
- https://vec.io/posts/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk

EDIT: I updated the first link with a more recent article (it uses `NDK r9`).

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestions here. A few of these links I have seen before but it seems I didn't look into the last one deep enough since that could be what I was looking for. Ill be sure to come back after testing and mark what worked for me. Thanks!