# ffmpeg-Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to execute below command using [ffmpeg-android-java](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/)

> -i /storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp
>   Video/VID-20170228-WA0000.mp4 -ss 180 -t 292 -strict -2 -async 1
>   /storage/sdcard0/Movies/cropper_video_1.mp4

I am getting below failure message-

> FAILED with output : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the
>   FFmpeg developers
>                                                                                                 built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>                                                                                                 configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
>   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>                                                                                                 libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
>                                                                                                 libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
>                                                                                                 libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
>                                                                                                 libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
>                                                                                                 libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
>                                                                                                 libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>                                                                                                 libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>                                                                                                 libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>                                                                                               Unrecognized option 'i /storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp
>   Video/VID-20170228-WA0000.mp4 -ss 180 -t 292 -strict -2 -async 1
>   /storage/sdcard0/Movies/cropper_video_1.mp4'.
>                                                                                               Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Why am i getting this error and how can i resolve it?

Comment: Looks like a dash missing before i :  `-i /storage....`

Comment: @Mulvya I am adding dash..forgot to put there..not working..same error

Comment: Your error log shows otherwise: `Unrecognized option 'i /storage/sdcard0...` Maybe your quotes and string is malformed.

Comment: can you post your android String array here

Answer (score 7):

I faced a very similar issue. The command I gave was

```
"-y -i /sdcard/Movies/test_video.3gp /sdcard/Movies/test_video.mp4"
```

And I got following error

> Unrecognized option 'y -i /sdcard/Movies/test_video.3gp
>   /sdcard/Movies/test_video.mp4'. Error splitting the argument list:
>   Option not found

The reason was, I was giving my command in a single String. Instead you have to break each command to its own String and provide a String array

```
val command: List<String> = listOf("-y", "-i", "/sdcard/Movies/test_video.3gp", "/sdcard/Movies/test_video.mp4")
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue is that the shell command required here needs you to split your string at whitespaces so that there are none.

The easiest way to do that would be :-

```
String ffmpegCmdString = "-y -i /sdcard/Movies/test_video.3gp /sdcard/Movies/test_video.mp4"

String[] splitCmd = ffmpegCmdString.split(" ");
```

You can now pass this splitCmd variable to run your command and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It means some features of ffmpeg are not fully implemented for this build.
The solutions:
1. Create your custom build for ffmpeg for Android.
2. Remove `-strict -2 -async 1` flags

Comment: is there some tutorial to create custom build for ffmpeg ?removing e -strict -2 -async 1 not working..same error

Comment: @Stranger , I created custom builds for ffmpeg two year ago. I used this topics: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22259969/1979882 . I used NDK for custom build. This is reather difficult, imho. But , nay be nowadays android  studio can help to you.

Comment: @Stranger , better question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277628/android-how-to-configure-ffmpeg-latest-version-in-android-studio